# Why can some but not all Letsencrypt websites not be read?

Tags: c#, webrequest, lets-encrypt

After some webserver updates today the script I use that loads data from one of my websites stopped working! The website uses Letsencrypt for SSL.

I tried to read all kind of websites that use Letsencrypt (see code below), including Letsencrypt.org itself. Some work, some don't. I would like to know what is going on. Anyone?

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //string site = "https://www.rtl.nl/";  // <-- Not a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, runs fine
        //string site = "https://weblog.west-wind.com/"; // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, runs fine.
        //string site = "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/";  // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, runs fine
        //string site = "https://letsencrypt.org/"; // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, results in exception!
        //string site = "https://www.shopify.com/"; // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, results in exception!
        //string site = "https://keenetic.com/en"; // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, runs fine
        string site = "https://unraid.net/"; // <-- LetsEncrypt SSL certificate, results in exception!

        HttpWebRequest myWeb = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);
        string myPage = "";

        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
            WebResponse myResponse = myWeb.GetResponse();
            Stream myStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
            myPage = myReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
            textBox1.Text = "Runs fine!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "SSL/TLS Exception!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message(s) might help...

Comment: looking at a few of the sites, the ones that work seem to use TLS 1.2, the ones that don't use TLS 1.3. Maybe an old .net version that doesn't support TLS 1.3?

Comment: Or dont explicitly set it to TSL 1.2?

Comment: The error message is in Dutch, that is why I didn't post it, but Google translated it for me:  "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: It might be TSL 1.3! Dot NET 4.7.2. is the highest I can use with my current VS. I will compile with VS 2019 and let you know the result. THANX!

Comment: Stefan, you mean "SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;"? I've tries all settings here, no difference with/without all ServicePointManager lines btw.

Answer (score 1):

The code above was compiled in VS 2015 (quite old!)
I tried it in VS 2017 and all sites run fine.

TLS 1.3 is probably the cause for the exceptions.
I'll move to VS 2019 tonight! :-)

Thanks Dirk and Stefan for solving this.